# Child’s swing going sideways

Tags: swing

My sons metal A-Frame swing has started twisting to the point that  instead of swinging in the usual pendulum 12 to 6 motion, he ends up going at 10 to 4 (if that makes sense). I’ve tried moving the legs further apart, and closer together and levelling into out the brackets at the top that the rope hangs on but nothing I do seems to change anything.

Any help would be much appreciated, it was the one activity that kept him quiet during lockdown!

Comment: Does it swing that way if another person uses it? You would want to rule out any personal effect caused by the user before taking radical steps...

Answer (score 1):

I built a large swing for my grand children what I learned having the A frame legs wider at the base about a 15 degree angle and then having the swing supports , chain, or rope a similar spread did the trick.

Originally I had the supports the same width as the seat and they would end up swinging at an angle, I went and measured several swing’s at our local park and found that they were wider at top, after moving the brackets out the swings now swing true.

I had tried all kinds of things changing from chains to ropes changing the length I had even tried taking the base out of level (this was a dumb thing and a lot of work)

After everything the wider at the top did the trick it kind of makes sense but I thought the swing needed to go straight up after measuring 2 different swings at the park I tried it and what a difference , it doesn’t affect their ability to get going or no one ever noticed but it did stabilize the travel.